# Question about perimeter of a sector of a circle

Tags: circles

[image]

I need to find the radius. The answer says "$3.79$ or $3.793$ to $3.974$" but I am not quite sure how to get there.

Why is this method wrong: $$3(65/360 × 2π × r)+ 6r = 20.5.$$ (Sorry for poor editing)

Comment: i figured its the 3 sectors added up to get perimeter. Why arent they part of the perimeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but take a look at the figure one more time. Why do you add $6r$? There are $3$ circle sectors, and $2$ straight lines (equal in length to the radius). The length of the perimeter should therefore be $$3(\frac{65}{360}\times2\pi r)+2r=20.5$$

Comment: erm i thought its 3 sectors added up to get the perimeter

Comment: Put your finger on the figure, and trace out the path around.

Comment: So its the outer path that gives the perimeter, I understand. But why isnt all the radii of the sectors included?

Comment: Because you're only going around the outer part of the figure, you're not going inside

Comment: So 3 arc lengths + 2 radii?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the diagram, if the radius is $R$ and the perimeter is $P$, we get that the perimeter consists of $2$ radiuses (left and right), and $3$ parts of the perimeter.

$$2R + 3(2\pi R \times \frac{65^\circ}{360^\circ}) = P$$

I assume you can figure out the rest yourself.